# Правильно ли я решил задачу замены Login на Logout в языке PHP в MVC-проекте?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток всем программистам!

Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я решил задачу.

Итак, на курсе изучения ПХП мне поставили слудуюющую задачу - на условном сайте интернет-магазина в меню есть 2 пункта: "Зарегистрироватсья" и "Войти". После того как услов. посетитель ввел правильные логин и пароль - эти 2 пункта меню должны смениться соответственно на: "имя_фамилия_пользователя" и "Выйти". Также есть требование - пока посетитель не "разлогинился" - на всех страницах (в шапке) "должны быть" надписи "имя_фамилия_пользователя" и "Выйти".

Я задачу выполнил - все так и происходит.
Не знаю как правильно это делать, но я эту задачу реализовал следующим способом: создал копию начального файла "mainmenu.php" (где слова: "Зарегистрироватсья" и "Войти"+соотв.иконка) (+еще 1 копия каждого из этих файлов) и соот.метод, который делает манипуляцию с этими 2 файлами.

Думаю Вы поняли какие манипуляции происходят - метод реаигрует на ЛОГИН- и ЛОГАУТ-действия пользователя: переименовывает один файл, удаляет другой и т.д.

Все работает идеально (на локальной машине).

Но меня терзают сомнения - что в "реальной жизни" (много пользователей зашли на сайт в один и тот же момент времени) "такая система работать" не будет или будет давать осечку/ошибки или будет задерживать пользователей или опасна с точки зрения безопасности сайта.

Что Вы думаете по этому поводу?

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Всё не правильно. Это должно быть реализовано посредством  [сессий](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php), а не манипулированием файлами

Answer (score 0):

ваше решение в будущем вызовет много проблем в будуще, я бы советовал все реализовать по другому.

1. Нужно использовать сессии, по сути сессии используют файловую систему, но php имеет целый набор инструменов что бы работать с ними и будущих проекта вы точно столкнетесь с сессиями. Есть и другие способы авторизации, но пока я вам советую сфокусироватся на сессиях.
2. Хранить данные пользователей стоит в БД, можете использовать mysql. Если работаете с windows то скорее всего вы пользуетеся open server там уже есть сервис mysql (пользователь root, без пароля).

Вот небольшое руководство:
https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=497962

Важно: Данное руководство имеет много недочетов, так это просто для понимая что надо реализовать. На будущие познакомтесь с темой SQL Injection.